# how to replace a part of an image in html5

Tags: image, html, canvas

This is the first time I ask question here,I'm sorry about my english skill.
My useage beblow:
We use websocket for server to communicat with client.The server send image to client and eachtime there just a little difference between the images.So,How to display the images with the highest performance?
I think,I can get the difference bytes from the typed array of image,and just replace them,but how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

If your server knows what is different from what came before, then it can create a transparent image that only has the different bits in it and you can just stack that image on top of the previous image(s). In the places that it is the same as before, it can just be transparent (no image data).  The relatively small amount of different data should compress into a pretty small image file.

Comment: Yes,We did it as what you write。But if I use img.src="url" to display the image,the browser will draw a new image fully.How to make the browser just draw difference part of the image?

Comment: @kyo - You can stack new images on top of one another using CSS to position them that way.  You can't make a browser draw just part of an `<img>` tag. You could explore using canvas drawing functions.